# .NET CORE 3.1 DATABASE FİRST How to access the name of Id received with foreign key

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm working on a project using database first with .NET core 3.1 .When I access the column information of the ID received with the Foreign key, it is null.

**User Model**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Article = new HashSet<Article>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserSurname { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public int? RolId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RolId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Role.User))]
    public virtual Role Rol { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Article { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Role Model**

```
public partial class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            User = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Rol")]
        public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AdventureContext**

```
 public partial class AdventureContext : DbContext
    {
        public AdventureContext()
        {
        }
        public AdventureContext(DbContextOptions<AdventureContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Images> Images { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
               optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-Q779BF0\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=cmsData;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Category)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Article)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Article_Category");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Image)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Article)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ImageId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Article_Images");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Article)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Article_User");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Article)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Comment)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ArticleId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Comment_Article");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Rol)
                    .WithMany(p => p.User)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RolId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_User_Role");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**View**

> @foreach (var item in Model)
>                   {
>                       
>                           
>                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
>                           
>                           
>                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserSurname)
>                           
>                           
>                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
>                           
>                           
>                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserEmail)
>                           
>                           
>                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rol.RoleName)
>                            }

I want to get rolename. Why not coming ?
        [UserIndex List View][1]
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f2CZ.png

Comment: How does your controller look like? how do you query the users? did you include the roles like in the docs?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I just list the table in the controller                                                                                             var list = db.User.ToList();
            return View(list); @hujtomi

Comment: You should try `var list = db.User.Include(u => u.Rol).ToList();` like in the Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the related entities in your controller action method. Something like this:

```
var list = db.User.Include(u => u.Rol).ToList();
```

You can read more about how to load related entities in the Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data